# In Android Studio open java editor and layout preview same time

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio,are there any way to open java editor and XML Preview together in same time.When doing the development we always have to select id's from the xml layout by opening it.even if i press the Ctrl+Space in the findViewById method it will give all the id's and i have to choose correct id.are there any easy way to do this??.In the X-code IDE have some feature to bind layout element to the code.are there any feature in Android Studio or Eclips like this.(This might be a stupid question but this type feature makes coding very fast)

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

**Side by Side Tabs**

In the MAC version of the Android Studio go to the menu item

`Window > Editor Tabs`

then either select

`Split Vertically`, or 
`Split Horizontally`.

Then, you should see two editors at the same time. These are, however, not linked. You need to link them manually.

**Naming Convention**

An easy way of choosing the correct id of an element is to first make up an easy to use and memorize naming convention. I use the following (an excerpt only):

- Ids that are mapped to member attributes

  - m_lbl_    (label)
  - m_btn_    (button)
  - m_tv_     (text view)
  - m_lv_     (list view)
  - m_rv_     (relative view)

---

- ids in menus

  - menu_itm_     (menu item)

---

- strings that are only shown, but not dynamically changed

  - str_          (simple string)
  - str_menu_     (menu item)
  - str_btn_      (button label)
  - str_tv_       (string in text view)

---

- toast messages

  - str_toast_

---

Equally, I use a naming convention for ids.